# Use both time and canceler to abort $http calls

Tags: angularjs

I have an application which allows the user to do a search and get data. In each search, there are **5** `$http` calls for getting data from back end. And I set 5s timeout for each `$http` call.

```
$http.get(url, {timeout: 5000});
```

In addition, I want to abort all ongoing `$http` calls when the user does a new search. So, [I can use a canceler](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx).

```
var canceler = $q.defer();
$http.get(url, {timeout: canceler.promise});

$scope.cancel = function(){
    canceler.resolve("ajax aborted");  
};
```

As you can see, the user can do a new search before the 5s timeout. So how can I use both time and canceler here? And is there any way in AngularJs that I can do this (abort all the 5 `$http` calls) more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a timeout that would resolve your canceler promise 5000ms after the user started a new search ?

```
$scope.startSearch = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
        canceler.resolve("time out :(");  
    }, 5000);
};
```

You could add a check to see if the promise has been resolved:

```
// set resolved to false each time you use your $http request
var canceler = $q.defer(), resolved = false;

$scope.cancel = function(){
    if(resolved) return;
    resolved = true;
    canceler.resolve("ajax aborted");
};

$scope.startSearch = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
        if(resolved) return;
        canceler.resolve("time out :(");
        resolved = true;
    }, 5000);
};
```

or you could do something like this:

```
$scope.startSearch = function(){
    stop = $timeout(function() {
        canceler.resolve("time out :(");
    }, 5000);
    canceler.promise.then(function() { stop() });
};
```

Comment: Oh right, my edits do not require approval anymore. Feel free to roll it back, but I was thinking the use of "every 5000ms" was misleading.

Comment: I spotted it too and was about to correct it, but you beat me at it ;)

Comment: Thanks for you answer